# How can I have a one to many relationship and join it using a different column?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm working with 2 models.

```
class Foo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    desc = db.Column(db.String(30))

    bars = db.relationship('Bar', back_populates='foo')


class Bar(db.Model):
    key_1 = db.Column(db.String('64'), primary_key=True)
    key_2 = db.Column(db.String('64'), primary_key=True)
    up_foo = db.Column(db.String('64'), primary_key=True)

    foo_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('foo.id'))
    foo = relationship('Foo', back_populates='bars')
```

What I'm trying to do is join `Foo` and `Bar`, but on field `up_foo` from the `Bar` table. My query would look like

```
select * from foo f
inner join bar b on f.id = b.up_foo
```

But it seems no matter which way I configure my relationships I get one of 2 errors. The first being that SQLAlchemy can't locate any relevant foreign key columns. And the second being that I can't map column `up_foo` twice because it's already a primary key, thus can't map it as a foreign key as well.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you also show the code when declaring up_foo as foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can indicate that one of the columns is both part of the composite `primary key` as well as a `foreign_key`. Of course, it also requires that those columns are of the same type. The code below should work just fine:

```
class Foo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    desc = db.Column(db.String(30))

    bars = db.relationship('Bar', back_populates='foo')


class Bar(db.Model):
    key_1 = db.Column(db.String(64), primary_key=True)
    key_2 = db.Column(db.String(64), primary_key=True)
    up_foo = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('foo.id'), primary_key=True)

    foo = db.relationship('Foo', back_populates='bars')
```

In which case your query is very straightforward, as you do not even need to specify a join condition:

```
q = db.session.query(Foo, Bar).join(Bar)
```